# ADF toTimetsamp() function not including 'T' in date pattern

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to convert string to timestamp (required for further processing). Date format I require is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss". As you can observe in below screenshot, 'T' is missing in the output. Is there any way to include 'T' in the output?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft official document, `toTimestamp` doesn't inculude `T` in the output.

`toTimestamp('2016-12-31T00:12:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss', 'PST') -> toTimestamp('2016-12-31 00:12:00')`

Refer [toTimestamp()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#totimestamp) to know more.

You can use another approach. Go to the **Schema** of the Sink and change the column type to **DateTime**. In **Format** column mention the format as per your requirement as mentioned below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to convert the timestamp to a string and then use the REPLACE function to replace the SPACE character between the date and time to a 'T'.

i.e. replace('2016-12-31 00:12:00',' ','T') -> 2016-12-31T00:12:00